# How to set a flag properly

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a timer class, inside the class there is a flag. When we did not call init(), flag is 0. After we call init(), it will be set to 1. After we call end(), it will be set back to 0.

```
class TimerHao
{
 private:
    double seconds;
    int    flag=0;  //0: Have not start accumulation. 1: In accumulation, between init() and end();

 public:

    void init();
    void end();
};

void TimerHao::init() 
{
    if(flag!=0) { throw runtime_error( "ERROR!!! Cannot initial the timer before it is ended!" ); }
    ...
    flag=1;
}

void TimerHao::end()
{
    if(flag!=1) { throw runtime_error("ERROR!!! Cannot end the timer before it is initialized!");}
    ...
    flag=0;
}
```

I can use the code by:

```
 TimerHao timerhao;
 timerhao.init();
 ...
 timerhao.end();
 ...
 timerhao.init();
 ...
 timerhao.end();
 ...
```

I do not like to set flag to a integer number, I need to read the comment to understand its meaning. Actually, I use this type of flag a lot in my code, e.g. flag can be 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, each number means different things. Sometimes, I get confused about my own code, I have to read comments carefully to understand what I am doing. Is there a clear way to handle this flag? Thank you.

Comment: What about using an `enum` instead?

Comment: What you want is an enum

Comment: Add an `enum` for it.

Comment: For timers, prefer terminology like "start", especially as it compares with "end"

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, this really help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an enumeration and use that value in your code so the code is self-explanatory:

```
class TimerHao
{
 private:

    enum flag_states
    {
        FLAG_STATE_NOT_STARTED = 0,
        FLAG_STATE_IN_ACCUMULATION,
        // etc
    };

    double seconds;
    flag_states flag = FLAG_STATE_NOT_STARTED;  //0: Have not start accumulation. 1: In accumulation, between init() and end();

 public:

    void init();
    void end();
};

void TimerHao::init() 
{
    if(flag != FLAG_STATE_NOT_STARTED) { throw runtime_error( "ERROR!!! Cannot initial the timer before it is ended!" ); }

    flag = FLAG_STATE_IN_ACCUMULATION;
}

void TimerHao::end()
{
    if(flag != FLAG_STATE_IN_ACCUMULATION) { throw runtime_error("ERROR!!! Cannot end the timer before it is initialized!");}

    flag= FLAG_STATE_NOT_STARTED;
}
```

If you have access to C++11 you can even make it a scoped enumeration and disallow casting:

```
class TimerHao
{
 private:

    enum class flag_states
    {
        FLAG_STATE_NOT_STARTED = 0,
        FLAG_STATE_IN_ACCUMULATION,
        // etc
    };

    double seconds;
    flag_states flag = flag_states::FLAG_STATE_NOT_STARTED;  //0: Have not start accumulation. 1: In accumulation, between init() and end();

 public:

    void init();
    void end();
};

void TimerHao::init() 
{
    if(flag != flag_states::FLAG_STATE_NOT_STARTED) { throw runtime_error( "ERROR!!! Cannot initial the timer before it is ended!" ); }

    flag = flag_states::FLAG_STATE_IN_ACCUMULATION;
}

void TimerHao::end()
{
    if(flag != flag_states::FLAG_STATE_IN_ACCUMULATION) { throw runtime_error("ERROR!!! Cannot end the timer before it is initialized!");}

    flag= flag_states::FLAG_STATE_NOT_STARTED;
}
```

Comment: Why not storing `flag` as `flag_states` instead of `int`?

Comment: Thank you @Gill Bates, this really hep.